# How can I import values from given URL to python

Tags: python, json

How can I extract the value of the last price of the strike price 31,500.00 from the given URL in python?

https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/derivative_stock_watch.htm

LTP of 31,500.00 strike price is 64.60.

Comment: Take a look at beautifulsoup, requests and web scraping

Comment: Yes, I did that. I am not able to understand what should be the tag value for "last price". When I inspect the website, multiple values on the page are assigned with 'td.number'.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work. The original webpage loads the data via ajax request using the url that i have used in the below code. So the actual data was in a different url. Try to read more on how to analyse the request and response flow in a website using chrome dev tools and also read more about BeautifulSoup python library.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/fomktwtch_top20Contrct.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select('#myTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(5)')[0].get_text())
print(soup.select('#myTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(10)')[0].get_text())
```

Output:

```
31,500.00
64.60
```